# Elasticsearch search term aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mappings:

```json
{
  mappings: {
    properties: {
      id: { type: "keyword" },
      tags: {
        properties: {
          text: { type: "text" },
          keyword: { type: "keyword" },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Here is some example data:

```json
[
  {
    id: '05070ff6-a7f1-4fad-ad70-e91fd87d58fb',
    tags: ['these','are','some','tags']
  },
  {
    id: '4843beba-4621-474f-bd80-281300fd0091',
    tags: ['abc']
  }
]
```

My query looks like this:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "tags.text": "are"
              }
            },
            {
              "prefix": {
                "tags.text": "are"
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "tags.text": {
                  "value": "*are*",
                  "case_insensitive": true
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "tags.text": {
                  "value": "*are",
                  "case_insensitive": true
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "tags.text": {
                  "value": "are*",
                  "case_insensitive": true
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "uniq_tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tags.keyword",
        "size": 500
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect the response to return ['are'] but it instead returns ['these', 'are, 'some, 'tags'].

I know I need to aggregate before filtering but my issue is that I need to filter on tags.text but Elasticsearch wants me to aggregate on `tags.keyword`. I'm not sure how to format the query to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to get only matching tags back you should use [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/nested.html) field with [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/query-dsl-nested-query.html) query
2. Aggregations only work on keyword fields (there is a way to apply them to text fields with [fielddata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param) parameter but this is not recommended) so you'll have to run query on `tags.text` but aggregations on `tags` (or whatever it will be with `nested`)